# Hong Kong stocks and HSI - Turnover and market cap in HKD?

Tags: equities, currency

Hello sorry newbie questions - HSI (Hang Seng Index) and stocks under it, dividend,Turnover and Market Cap always in USD or in local currency HKD?
This is actually a broader questions for Asian markets.

Thanks

https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview/1810.HK
http://www.aastocks.com/en/mobile/Quote.aspx?symbol=00005
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EHSI/

Comment: Downvote as this questions does not have anything to do with Quant finance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in hong kong dollar.

You can see HK$ is indicated:
https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en